# How to send DTMF signal in Symbian S60

Tags: symbian, nokia, sip, dtmf

I am new to Symbian development. I am developing a VOIP [SIP protocol] app for Nokia Symbian S60 3rd edition. I want to send DTMF signal through my app. But couldn't find any clue. So how can I send and catch DTMF signals in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/GUID-E35887BB-7E58-438C-AA27-97B2CDE7E069/GUID-9C5A86D2-E602-55AE-B54B-8511E70CD23D.html

Comment: I think it'll not work, as far I learned it is used for GSM, but I am using SIP/VOIP telephony. @juuso-ohtonen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VoIP world you send SIP INFO messages with the DTMF data to the SIP server. For example to send the digit '1':

```
INFO sip:7007471000@example.com SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP alice.uk.example.com:5060
From: <sip:7007471234@alice.uk.example.com>;tag=d3f423d
To: <sip:7007471000@example.com>;tag=8942
Call-ID: 312352@myphone
CSeq: 5 INFO
Content-Type: application/dtmf-relay
Content-Length:    22

Signal=1
Duration=160
```

See also [this link](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/SIP+Info+DTMF).

If you want "traditional" DTMF messages over the RTP, the best way is to have the DTMF signals recorded (1.wav, 2.wav, etc) and play them it back during the call.